# What is the multiplicative order of this number

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $q, r \in \mathbb{P}$ and $r$ is the next prime to $q$.

What is the **multiplicative order** of $r$ modulo $\displaystyle\bigg( \prod_{\substack{p \leq q \\\text{p prime}}} p \bigg)$ ?

In other word what is the smallest $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ verifying :
$$r^k = 1 \pmod{\prod_{\substack{p \leq q \\\text{p prime}}} p}$$

Using **Euler theorem** we know that $k$ divide $\phi \displaystyle\bigg( \prod_{\substack{p \leq q \\\text{p prime}}} p \bigg) = \prod_{\substack{p \leq q \\\text{p prime}}} (p - 1)$

**Many thanks for any help**

---

**Edit 20/09/2020 :** The sequence is added here : https://oeis.org/A333992

Comment: $k$ is the least common multiple of orders of $r$ modulo $p$ for all $p\leq q$, so in particular it divides the least common multiple of all the $p-1,p\leq q$. I doubt you will get a formula any more explicit than that.

Comment: @Wojowu Just out of curiosity - dividing that lcm by the number in question gives the sequence $1,1,1,2,3,1,2,5,1,3,3,7,2,22,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,4,12,5,2,6,1,1,5,1,1,2,1,6,82,1,1,...$

Comment: Thank you @მამუკაჯიბლაძე and Wojowu for your contributions.

Comment: Seems not to be in the OEIS.  I encourage you to contribute it.

Comment: Thank you Mr Robert, i will add it.